# Curator.io mobile feed close button disappearance

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using curator.io aggregator to display Instagram feed on my website.

The problem is when I switch to mobile view the close button (class="crt-close") disappears
[image: close button disappear]

Here is an example: https://www.ilovecairns.com.au/social

You can reproduce by opening any post, then resize screen resolution to mobile.

[image: close button disappear]

Can anyone provide a custom CSS/JavaScript to maintain that close button functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I inspected is: The icon is behind and needed to increase the `z-index` property to bring in front starting from 910px screen width and there is a white background that needs to be hidden. Try these CSS. If somehow, it doesn't work then you can try with `z-index: 11 !important;` and same with the `background-color` if necessary.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 910px){
    .crt-popup-wrapper .crt-popup .crt-close{
        z-index: 11;
        background-color: none;
    }
}
```